# Cookie is not being saved when logging in with the Reddit API

Tags: python, django, cookies, reddit

I would like to add the [login](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API%3A-login) feature of the reddit API, but the cookie is not being saved. The following code is being called in a custom Authentication Backend, which is installed higher in the stack than Django's own ModelBackend.

```
response = requests.post(REDDIT_LOGIN_URL, data={'user' : username, 
                                                 'passwd' : password})
cookie = SimpleCookie()
cookie.load(response.headers.get('set-cookie'))
```

printing cookie['reddit_session'] returns a Morsel (obfuscated)

```
<Morsel: reddit_session='5356323%2C2012-05-15T17%3A15%3A08%xxxxxxxxxxxx7a4f25351b003a2484'>
```

This Cookie, however, is nowhere found in my browser. When the page is reloaded, my reddit session is gone, and I can not use other reddit API calls unless I create this session again.
When I use the Chrome developer tools to look at my cookies, I see an entry under Resources > Cookies called "blank". When I click this, all I get is a white page with "This site has no cookies"

I am doing this in django-1.4, with

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
```

enabled in settings.py. I tried it without with the same results.

Am I missing something here? I've tried using [narwa](http://narwal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) as well, and the cookie is not being saved either. My cookies are definitely enabled in my browser as the same Django session is saving the django_language and session_id cookies.

Any pointers or answers are appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you use HttpResponse_object.set_cookie method to drop the cookie in the browser?

Comment: Is your problem persistent across all browsers?

Comment: Is it consistent among all browsers. Shouldn't SimpleCookie drop the cookie? Since I'm getting the Reddit response in an Authentication Backend module, I don't have the HttpResponse object available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure, but when I'm playing around with the API, I only need to store the `modhash` and send that in with my requests. Also, if you're using the `requests` module, use a session instance instead, and it will store the cookies across calls. I'm not sure how that'd play into Django at all though. Here's the code I wrote for logging in:

```
def login(username, password):
    """logs into reddit, saves cookie"""

    print 'begin log in'
    #username and password
    UP = {'user': username, 'passwd': password, 'api_type': 'json',}
    headers = {'user-agent': '/u/STACKOVERFLOW\'s API python bot', }
    #POST with user/pwd
    client = requests.session()

    r = client.post('http://www.reddit.com/api/login', data=UP)

    #print r.text
    #print r.cookies

    #gets and saves the modhash
    j = json.loads(r.text) #I believe r.json == j at this point

    client.modhash = j['json']['data']['modhash']
    print '{USER}\'s modhash is: {mh}'.format(USER=username, mh=client.modhash)

    #pp2(j)

    return client
```